# Openldap enable ssl on replication

Tags: ldap, openldap

Can you told me how can i modify current configuration for olcSyncRepl?

I have following situation:

1. I Configured master ldap server and slave server
2. I Configured replication between these two servers (Everything is working)
3. I have following configuration for slave client:

> ```
> dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
> changetype: modify
> add: olcSyncRepl
> olcSyncRepl: rid=001
>   provider=ldap://10.101.11.130:389/
>   bindmethod=simple
>   binddn="uid=rpuser,dc=itzgeek,dc=local"
>   credentials=root1234
>   searchbase="dc=itzgeek,dc=local"
>   scope=sub
>   schemachecking=on
>   type=refreshAndPersist
>   retry="30 5 300 3"
>   interval=00:00:05:00
> ```

And I want to add:

1. Credential not as plain-text ( I want to add {SSHA}.... )
2. Add certificates (I have also enabled ldaps with self-signed certificates .crt and .key)

I would like to advise you how to safely configure it, modify it. I do not want to spoil the current server settings. For example, how could I change the IP address of the current master server? If someone will answer it, I will be able to test the rest of the set changes

PS

I know that it is possible to modify files in /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config
but can you told me how can i use ldif files and ldapi to update config ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on which OpenLDAP builds you're using on which OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reference I post syncrepl directives used in [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com):

```
olcSyncrepl: rid=001
  provider=ldaps://ae-dir-p1.example.com
  bindmethod=sasl
  saslmech=EXTERNAL
  starttls=no
  tls_cert="/opt/ae-dir/etc/tls/ae-dir-c1.example.com.crt"
  tls_key="/opt/ae-dir/etc/tls/ae-dir-c1.example.com.key"
  tls_cacert="/opt/ae-dir/etc/tls/my-ae-dir-testca-2017-06.pem"
  tls_reqcert=demand
  crlcheck=none
  filter="(objectClass=*)"
  searchbase="dc=ae-dir,dc=example,dc=org"
  scope=sub
  schemachecking=on
  type=refreshAndPersist
  retry="30 +"
```

First of all you should not use an IP address in LDAP URL for `provider=`. Rather get a correctly issued TLS server cert for the hostname and then OpenLDAP *slapd* will conduct the correct TLS hostname check to prevent MITM attacks (see [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125)).

I assume that you have TLS configured on your provider **and** consumer instances. The above syncrepl configuration uses the already configured TLS **server** certificate also as TLS **client** certificate for replication.

In case of TLS client certs the resulting **authentication** identity (authc-DN) is the subject DN in the client certificate. You might want to map that to an authorization identity (authz-DN) of an existing LDAP entry. This can be achieved by adding *olcAuthzRegexp* to *cn=config* like this:

```
olcAuthzRegexp:
  "(cn=[^,]+,OU=ITS,O=My Org)"
  "ldap:///dc=ae-dir,dc=example,dc=org??sub?(&(objectClass=pkiUser)(seeAlso=$1)(seeAlso:dnSubordinateMatch:=OU=ITS,O=My Org)(aeStatus=0))"
```

With the above a subject DN ending with `OU=ITS,O=My Org` will be mapped to an LDAP entry with object class *pkiUser* with the client cert's subject DN stored in attribute *seeAlso* like this:

```
dn: uid=ae-dir-slapd_ae-dir-deb-c1,cn=ae,dc=ae-dir,dc=example,dc=org
aeStatus: 0
cn: ae-dir-slapd_ae-dir-deb-c1
memberOf: cn=ae-replicas,cn=ae,dc=ae-dir,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: account
objectClass: aeObject
objectClass: aeService
objectClass: pkiUser
objectClass: posixAccount
seeAlso: cn=ae-dir-c1.example.com,OU=ITS,O=My Org
[..]
```

You can then properly authorize this service user entry, in the above example via LDAP group *ae-replicas*.